# Add label text on table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitableview

How can i convert labels to integers and sum all of them up

```
    var totalCount:Int?
    if let number = Int(price.text!) {
        let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:number)
        totalCount = totalCount! + myNumber.integerValue
        print(totalCount)
    } else {
        print("'\(price.text)' did not convert to an Int")
    }
```

here is my code it is not working

Comment: You can't convert labels to integers.You can convert label text to integer if you get numbers in text.

Comment: which line u face this issue

Comment: let output  = Int(price.text!)
print (output) - is the conversion

Comment: @user3182143 Yes i am talking about the text

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This wont add them up will just print out

Comment: @lordxxx - it is else block you need to add conversion/type case

Comment: @lordxxx - you want to add totalCount to price.text

Comment: My method is not working do you have another method i can use to add up all the label text in all the cells

Answer (score 3):

Use this method.

```
var totalCount = 0
guard let priceString = price.text else {
   print("price label is nil")
   return
}
let myNumber = Int(priceString)
totalCount = totalCount + myNumber!
print(totalCount)
```

Comment: I still get each of the cell text printed out separately i want to get the sum of everything

Comment: You mean in the table view? and please show me your full source code for where you want to sum.

Comment: Here is the code http://pastebin.com/hXsCDC0d

Comment: i accessed your code, btw what result exactly do you want?

Comment: I want to get the total price by adding up the price for each cell

Comment: Hi, please post your full code not only configureCell method, I'm not sure when configureCell method is called.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EjHX2W81 This is the code for my cell and http://pastebin.com/f4LQgwfX this is the code for the tavleview

Answer (score 0):

Brother I tried your coding first it shows me the error when run time on this line

```
totalCount = totalCount! + myNumber.integerValue
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Then I set

```
var totalCount:Int = 0
var arr = [String]()
```

The tried sample coding is

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   var totalCount:Int = 0
   let priceValue: String = "100"
   arr.append(priceValue)
   self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

}
```

Then in tableView delegate methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    let priceVal = arr[indexPath.row]
    if let number = Int(priceVal)
    {
        let myNumber = NSNumber(integer:number)
        totalCount =  totalCount  + myNumber.integerValue
        print(totalCount)
    }
    else
    {
       print("'\(priceVal)' did not convert to an Int")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(totalCount)

    return cell
}
```

Printed result is

```
100
```

[Community wiki group answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Yes this will work but i have more than one cell so more than one text

Comment: Add the string objects to array

Comment: Can you update your answer please

Comment: lordxxx do you use tableview?

Comment: Yes i use tableview

Comment: Check my updated  answer brother.it works fine.

Comment: Do you get the solution now?